# MySQL order results by total by weights

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  p.`ID`,
  (SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `comments` c WHERE c.`post_id` = p.`ID`) AS `comments`,
  (SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `likes` l WHERE l.`post_id` = p.`ID`) AS `likes`
FROM `posts` p
```

I want to order the results according to the third column, which will be calculated the following way:

```
order = comments * 6 + likes * 4
```

How can I create this "virtual" column and use the results of the other two in a calculation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite your query this way:

```
SELECT
    p.ID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT comments.ID) as comments,
    COUNT(DISTINCT likes.ID) as likes,
    COUNT(DISTINCT comments.ID)* 6 + COUNT(DISTINCT likes.ID)* 4 as `order`
FROM
    posts p LEFT JOIN comments on p.id = comments.post_id
    LEFT JOIN likes` ON likes.`post_id` = p.`ID`
GROUP BY
    p.ID
ORDER BY
    `order`
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT p.ID, comments, likes, (comments * 6) + (likes * 4) AS ordering
FROM (

    SELECT
      p.`ID`,
      (SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `comments` c WHERE c.`post_id` = p.`ID`) AS `comments`,
      (SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `likes` l WHERE l.`post_id` = p.`ID`) AS `likes`
    FROM `posts`
) AS p
ORDER BY ordering
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marc - however I couldn't get this to work; it was returning an empty row without all necessary information. I managed to use fthiella's answer though.